# VBA variable takes no values

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim intCounter2 As Integer
Dim rngExchange As Range
Dim rngExchange2 As Range
Dim control As Integer
Dim control2 As Integer

intCounter = 1
intCounter2 = 1

Do While Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, intCounter2) <> ""
    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, intCounter2).Value = "Isin" Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            Set rngExchange2 = .Range(.Cells(2, intCounter2), .Cells(2, intCounter2))
            control2 = intCounter2
        End With
    End If
    intCounter2 = intCounter2 + 1
Loop
```

The code finds the column with title Isin and then I use the variable control2 for operations with this column. However, firstly the rngExchange2 does not takes the value "Isin" and secondly the control2 variable remains 0. Can you please help with that.

Comment: From what you say it seems that it does not enter the loop. The columns before "Isin" are all with values?

Comment: Why not use the `Find` method (of a range object)? Much quicker than looping cell by cell in VBA. Also, using `Integer` for cell indices is risking overflow. Use `Long` instead.

Comment: Did you check how is your code working by placing cursor somewhere in the code and pressing F8?

Comment: what is this even doing? doesnt seem like its doign anything at all?

Comment: Is the cell with "Isin" in it free of white space? "Isin" is different than " Isin ". Also be careful with the case "ISIN" is different than "Isin". My experience with ISINs and CUSIPs etc is they are often contain hidden white space inserted from fixed database column width definitions.

Comment: please explain clearly what you want to achieve? find continuous cells in row 2 with value of "Isin" or just first cell with such value?

Comment: You need to exit the loop after you find the column you're looking for. Add `Exit Do` after `End With`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your loop is wrong, it was corrected in a previous question.

But I suggest that you use something clearer to find the column of a specific text, like `Range.Find` method :

```
Sub test_Anton()
Dim SearchString As String
Dim ConTrol2 As Integer
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim cF As Range

SearchString = "Isin"

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With wS
    .Activate
    With .Range("2:2")
        .Cells(1, 1).Activate
        'First, define properly the Find method
        Set cF = .Find(What:=SearchString, _
                    After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)
        'If there is a result, stock the column
        If Not cF Is Nothing Then
            ConTrol2 = cF.Column
        Else
            MsgBox SearchString & " not found in " & wS.Name, vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        End If
    End With '.Range("2:2")
End With 'wS

MsgBox SearchString & " found in column " & ConTrol2 & " in sheet " & wS.Name, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are using .cells(2,intCounter2), the first parameter specifies the row, second parameter which is your variable is the column. I've tested your code with 
breakpoints in my own sheet and it seems to be able to find "Isin".

I would check that you have Isin in the right place and then also check the case of Isin to make sure that it matches what you have in your VBA code as it's case sensitive.

That should hopefully work for you.